# I hit the ENTER key on keyboard and page refreshes. How do I prevent this and still use the keyboard to search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We used to be able to enter a search field, address on search box, hit the ENTER key on the keyboard and get the search results.

I made several changes but can't pinpoint the change that resulted in the ENTER key misbehaving. Instead of submitting, it refreshes the page.

I have tried each of the following to stop the page refresh:

```
<form onSubmit="return false;">

<form onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13">
```

Each works.

However, I can no longer hit the ENTER key and have results displayed.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Below is the js:

```
function getData()
{

     dijit.byId("advanceSearchDialog").hide(); 
    var form = document.getElementById("searchForm");
    var form2 = document.getElementById("featuresForm")
    var searchText = form.searchBox.value.replace(/-/g,"");
    form.searchBox.value = searchText;

    if (searchText != "") 
    {
        // collect features to search for:
        var features = [ ];
        var featTypes = form2.featType;
        for ( var f = 0; f < featTypes.length; ++f )
        {
            if ( featTypes[f].checked ) features.push( featTypes[f].value );
        }
        featureList = "'" + features.join("','") + "'";

        searchMsg("Searching for '" + searchText + "' ...");
        featureID = "";
        var accord = dijit.byId("accordianContainer");
        var resultsPane = dijit.byId("resultsPane");
        accord.selectChild(resultsPane,true);
        doGlobalSearch( searchText, featureList );
    }
    else
    {
      searchMsg("No search criteria entered, enter search text");
    }   
}


function searchKey(e){
    // special case for IE to capture <enter> in the search box
    var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
    if (key == 13)
      getData();
}



<form id="searchForm" class="search_field" method="get" action="">
   <input name="searchBox" id="searchBox" value="" />
  <button type="button" onclick="getData()"><img src="images/magnifying_glass.png" alt="Search" /></button>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: We need to see the code that executes. I would expect onsubmit="return somefunction()" Also event.keyKode is IE only

Comment: Could you please give us the code of your auto-completion, or, preferrably, a jsfiddle?

Comment: If enter key is refreshing the page, that means your submit handler isn't preventing the default action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the onkeypress and use onsubmit instead since it is automatically called when the enter key is pressed on an input field of a form.

```
<form onsubmit="return getData()">
   <input name="searchBox" id="searchBox" value="" />
   <button type="submit"><img src="images/magnifying_glass.png" alt="Search" /></button>
</form>
```

js

```
function getData() {
    dijit.byId("advanceSearchDialog").hide(); 
    var form = document.getElementById("searchForm");
    var form2 = document.getElementById("featuresForm")
    var searchText = form.searchBox.value.replace(/-/g,"");
    form.searchBox.value = searchText;

    if (searchText != "") 
    {
        // collect features to search for:
        var features = [ ];
        var featTypes = form2.featType;
        for ( var f = 0; f < featTypes.length; ++f )
        {
            if ( featTypes[f].checked ) features.push( featTypes[f].value );
        }
        featureList = "'" + features.join("','") + "'";

        searchMsg("Searching for '" + searchText + "' ...");
        featureID = "";
        var accord = dijit.byId("accordianContainer");
        var resultsPane = dijit.byId("resultsPane");
        accord.selectChild(resultsPane,true);
        doGlobalSearch( searchText, featureList );
    }
    else
    {
      searchMsg("No search criteria entered, enter search text");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you are simply FANTASTIC!!! Thank you very sir. Worked like a dream on first try.

BUT I can't figure out the change you made on the js side. I can see the changes on the form but not on the js code.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh I only added `return false;`. Note the updates i just made to the button in the form.

Answer (score 6):

use just following simple jQuery

```
if(event.keyCode == 13){ 
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

...bind it to you form

Answer (score 4):

Whatever function you are calling to display your search results needs to either

- return false;

or

- call event.preventDefault();

This will avoid the default form action from being executed (causing a full page refresh).

Comment: I have updated code above with js. @mplungjan, etal, Sorry I misspoke. I believe the problem is with the getData() function because the searchKep() has been there and I didn't make any changes to it. I made changes to getData() function.

 Thanks for your help